# A constrained gradient descent algorithm

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am looking for a way to find a solution to the constrained minimization problem using the gradient descent Algorithm. it follows

```
min  J(T) where T=[T_1, T_2, ... , T_m]
s.t T_i > 0 for i=1,...,m
    sum(T) = constant
```

How can I use the constraints? It's very simple constraints but too hard for me now...

Comment: with such simple constraints you can cut your point back at the boundary if the line-search crosses the boundary. This is termed "truncated gradient" or "projected gradient method", one projects the point back to the closest admissible point. Often, this will give reasonable (not necessarily optimal) results. However, it is easy to construct "corner" cases where this strategy fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply gradient descent directly. Here are a few alternatives:

- If $J(T)$ is linear, this is a very simple problem to solve using Simplex Method or any other Linear Solver you want to choose.
- However, I assume $J(T)$ is not linear. If $J(T)$ is quadratic, you can use active-set QP solver to find the solution which again, is quite a mature technology.
- If $J(T)$ is not quadratic but something convex, you can use tools like [`CVX`](http://cvxr.com/) to solve your problem. Again, these tools are quite mature.
- If $J(T)$ is not even convex, then you can use Interior Point Methods or Penalty-based methods for solving the problem. There are [many softwares](http://coin-or.org) you can use.

If you give us more details about what $J(T)$ is, we might be able to give you a more appropriate solution.

Also, be careful when using strict inequalities in optimization. Numerical optimization only makes sense on compact sets (and hence, in $\Re^N$, closed and bounded). To see why this is true, try $\min_x x$ such that $x\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function):

> "squashes" a K-dimensional vector of real values to a K-dimensional vector $\sigma(z)$  of real values in the range [0, 1] that add up to 1.

I.e. do unconstrained min $J(\ softmax(\ T_{real}\ ))$ .